# No Internet on Ubuntu 15.04 host, but Internet on Virtualbox VM's. Possibly routing problem

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internet

I have a problem getting Internet on my laptop (Lubuntu 15.04) at my office. I have used this laptop for a couple of months with same conditions, so I'm not sure what could have changed during the vacations. I've followed the steps on this page: [Network Troubleshooting](http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/network-troubleshooting/). I have the problem when I try the routing part. I have an IP 169.254.1.130 assigned from DHCP and can connect to other devices on the network 169.254.1.xxx.

```
nmambre@NM-Lenovo-B50-45:~$ ip route
default via 169.254.1.1 dev eth0 
default via 169.254.1.1 dev eth0  proto static  metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  metric 400
```

So I have a default route, but can't ping anything outside my network.

```
nmambre@NM-Lenovo-B50-45:~$ ping -c3 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.138 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.138 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.138 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2016ms
pipe 3
```

I've disabled wlan0 to force going through eth0, but the ping go to lo (127.0.0.1)

```
nmambre@NM-Lenovo-B50-45:~$ ping -c3 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 127.0.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 127.0.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 127.0.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms
pipe 3
```

The strangest thing is I'm posting this question in a WinXP VM (VirtualBox) with bridged network with eth0 on the same host where I have the problems. I tried also a Debian with NAT network, and couldn't get to the internet, switching to bridged and was able to get internet there too.